# Customizting Reports in Kentico

Tags: kentico

Any one have an idea on how to add new parameters to reports in Kentico 9 I want to add from-to date parameters in **Top customers by number of orders** report but I don't know how to implement it?

I've checked [Kentico DOC](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K8/Creating+reports) but still I can't customize it, I can only add new fields but don't have idea how to link it with the query.

Also need to know if it possible to export only report to send it for importing it on another server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add **from date** and **to date** parameters for the **Top customers by number of orders** report:

1. In the Reporting application, edit the report and open the Parameters tab
2. Add a new field, named `FromDate`, of the **Date and time** type. Set the field caption, as well. Click Save
3. Create a new `ToDate` field, similar to step 2
4. Click on the General tab, and scroll to the bottom - find the **Tables** dropdown
5. Select `table` in the Tables dropdown, click on the ellipsis button, and click Edit
   [image: Tables edit menu]
6. In the **Query** field, add the following to the WHERE clause:

```sql
AND (OrderDate BETWEEN COALESCE(@FromDate, CAST('1753-1-1' AS DateTime)) AND COALESCE(@ToDate, CAST('9999-12-31' AS DateTime)))
```

The full query would look something like this:

```sql
SELECT . . .
WHERE . . .
    AND (OrderDate BETWEEN COALESCE(@FromDate, CAST('1753-1-1' AS DateTime)) AND COALESCE(@ToDate, CAST('9999-12-31' AS DateTime)))
GROUP BY . . .
```

This will add a condition to filter orders that have an `OrderDate` between `FromDate` and `ToDate` (which are selectable from the report filters). `COALESCE` is there to convert `NULL` values to minimum/maximum dates, in case some date filter values are not set.

Also, to export a report, simply right-click the table header, and choose the export format that is the best fit for your needs.

[image: Report export]

Comment: Nice explanation!